# What's the fastest way to iterate over an object's properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I know that I can iterate over an object's properties like this:

```
for (property in object)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I also know that the fastest way to iterate over an array in Javascript is to use a decreasing while loop:

```
var i = myArray.length;
while (i--)
{
    // do stuff fast
}
```

I'm wondering if there is something similar to a decreasing while loop for iterating over an object's properties.

**Edit:** just a word about the answers concerned with enumerability - I'm not.

Comment: This smells like misplaced/premature optimization... Are you sure this is the part of your code that needs optimization?

Comment: None of it "needs" optimization. I'm working with sets of 10k to 20k objects, so faster is better.

Comment: Remember to check hasOwnProperty(property) so you don't operate on members of your prototypes (unless you want to, of course).

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett The `for/in` loop does not enumerate inherited properties/methods

Comment: really?  so the advice at http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/ is no longer applicable?

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett, @Josh Stodola: for-in does not iterate over built-in properties and methods (specifically, those declared as "DontEnum" in the ECMAScript spec) but it *does* include inherited members that have been added to prototypes, as there is no way for a member added by a script to be declared "DontEnum". Note that Crockford's example is of a method that has been added to String.prototype, not of a built-in property of String.prototype

Comment: @Nick In my answer, I make it clear that all properties added programmatically *are* in fact enumerable.

Comment: @MattBall I know, its been five years, but would you mind taking a look at [my submission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25700742/2228771)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1) There are many different ways to enumerate properties:

- [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (iterates over enumerable properties of the object and its prototype chain)
- [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns the array of the enumerable properties, found directly on the object (not in its prototype chain)
- [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)  returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly on the object.
- If you're dealing with multiple objects of the same "shape" (set of properties), it might make sense to "pre-compile" the iteration code (see [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700742/1026)).
- [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) can't be used to iterate an arbitrary object, but can be used with a `Map` or a `Set`, which are both suitable replacements for ordinary Objects for certain use-cases.
- ...

Perhaps if you stated your original problem, someone could suggest a way to optimize.

2) I find it hard to believe that the actual enumeration is taking more than whatever you do with the properties in the loop body.

3) You didn't specify what platform you're developing for. The answer would probably depend on it, and the available language features depend on it too. E.g. in SpiderMonkey (Firefox JS interpreter) circa 2009 you could use `for each(var x in arr)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for_each...in)) if you actually needed the values, not the keys. It was faster than `for (var i in arr) { var x = arr[i]; ... }`.

V8 at some point [regressed the performance of `for..in` and subsequently fixed it](http://benediktmeurer.de/2017/09/07/restoring-for-in-peak-performance/). Here's a post on the internals of `for..in` in V8 in 2017:  https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/03/fast-for-in-in-v8.html

4) You probably just didn't include it in your snippet, but a faster way to do a `for..in` iteration is to make sure the variables you use in the loop are declared inside the function containing the loop, i.e.:

```
//slower
for (property in object) { /* do stuff */ }

//faster
for (var property in object) { /* do stuff */ }
```

5) Related to (4): while trying to optimize a Firefox extension I once noticed that extracting a tight loop into a separate function improved its performance ([link](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20412#c1)). (Obviously, it doesn't mean you should always do that!)

Comment: You should declare the var outside the for loop so it doesn't try to make a new function-local variable every time.

Comment: What makes you say that? That goes against my intuitive understanding of "var" (which is not "executed" at run-time, but rather scanned-for before a function starts executing) and I don't see anything in the spec about this. So I believe if it is in fact so in some engine, it would be something that can (and should) be fixed in the engine.

Comment: I concur. "There's no other way to enumerate properties than using `for..in`"  - That was not even true in 2009. [Pre-compilation to the rescue (of performance)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25700742/2228771)!

Comment: Declaring variables inside the `for..in` loop parenthesis makes no difference than declaring them previously or at the top of the function. Since JavaScript has function scope, the variable inside the loop gets hoisted to the top of the function even if it is declared inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Right, but not declaring the variables at all is slower

Comment: This answer is wrong. you can use Object.getOwnPropertyNames() which will give you an array with the keys. This is old feat by the way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira you're being too harsh. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` is very similar to `Object.keys()` (which I did mention writing this answer 12 years ago), and its existence doesn't change the fact that the question is too generic.

Comment: @Nickolay The question is too generic, for sure, although .keys and getOwnPropertyNames have a big difference as one don not iterate over the non enumerable properties and other do. Also, this forum is accessed everyday despite the fact its and old answer, so it's our responsibility to keep it correct nowadays. BTW the answer is complete now

Answer (score 54):

## UPDATE / TLDR;

As it turns out, this is the approach that, under the hood, makes [ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv) the fastest JSON validator library.

Also - someone took my idea to the next level, and used it to speed up "summing over an object's properties" by over 100x across the browser spectrum - [find his jsperf here](https://jsperf.com/object-iteration-with-pre-compiled-iterator/12):

[image]

The pink bar represents his "pre-compiled sum" approach which just leaves all the other approaches and operations in the dust.

**What is the trick?**

Using the pre-compiled sum approach, he used my code to automatically generate this code:

```
var x = 0;
x += o.a;
x += o.b;
x += o.c;
// ...
```

which is way faster than this:

```
var x = 0;
for (var key in o) {
  x += o[key];
}
```

...especially if the order in which we access the properties (`a`, `b`, `c`) matches the order in `o`'s [hidden class](https://medium.com/faster-javascript/hidden-classes-in-javascript-and-inline-caching-6bc2a318c4b4).

Long explanation follows:

## Faster object property loops

Let me start by saying, `for ... in` loops are just fine, and you only want to think of this in performance-critical code with a lot of CPU and RAM usage. Usually, there is more important stuff you should spend your time on. However, if you are a performance-freak, you might be interested in this near-perfect alternative:

## Javascript Objects

Generally, there are two use-cases for JS objects:

1. "Dictionaries", a.k.a "associative arrays" are general containers with a **varying set of properties**, indexed by string keys.
2. "Objects of constant type" (for which the so-called [hidden class](https://medium.com/faster-javascript/hidden-classes-in-javascript-and-inline-caching-6bc2a318c4b4) is always the same) have a **fixed set of properties of fixed order**. Yes! - While the standard does not guarantee any order, modern VM implementations all do have a (hidden) order, to speed things up. It will be crucial to always maintain that order, as we explore later.

Using "objects of constant type" instead of "dictionary types" is generally a whole lot faster because the optimizer understands the structure of these objects. If you are curious as to how to achieve that, you might want to check out [Vyacheslav Egorov's blog](https://medium.com/faster-javascript) which sheds a whole lot of light on how [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) but also other Javascript run-times, work with objects. [Vyacheslav explains Javascript's object property look-up implementation in this blog entry](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html#dynamic-lookup-101).

## Looping over an object's properties

The default `for ... in` is certainly an Ok choice to iterate over all properties of objects. However, `for ... in` might treat your object as a dictionary with string keys, even if it has a hidden type. In that case, in every iteration you have the overhead of a dictionary lookup, which is often implemented as a [hashtable lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). In many cases, the optimizer is smart enough to avoid that, and performance is on par with constant naming of your properties, but it is simply not guaranteed. Often enough, the optimizer can't help you, and your loop will run a whole lot slower than it should. The worst thing is though that sometimes that is unavoidable, especially if your loop gets more complex. Optimizers are just not that smart (yet!). The following pseudocode describes how `for ... in` works in slow mode:

```
for each key in o:                                // key is a string!
    var value = o._hiddenDictionary.lookup(key);  // this is the overhead
    doSomethingWith(key, value);
```

An unrolled, un-optimized `for ... in` loop, looping over an object with three properties ['a', 'b', 'c'] of given order, looks like this:

```
var value = o._hiddenDictionary.lookup('a');
doSomethingWith('a', value);
var value = o._hiddenDictionary.lookup('b');
doSomethingWith('b', value);
var value = o._hiddenDictionary.lookup('c');
doSomethingWith('c', value);
```

Assuming that you cannot optimize `doSomethingWith`, [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) tells us that you can gain a lot of performance if and only if:

1. `doSomethingWith` is very fast already (when compared to the cost of the dictionary lookup) and
2. you can actually get rid of that dictionary lookup overhead.

We can indeed get rid of that lookup using, what I call, a **pre-compiled iterator**, a dedicated function that iterates over all objects of a fixed type, i.e. a type with a fixed set of properties of fixed order, and performing a specific operation on all of them. That iterator explicitly calls a callback (let's call it `doSomethingWith`) on each of your properties by their proper name. As a result, the run-time can always make use of the type's [hidden class](http://blog.twokul.io/hidden-classes-in-javascript-and-inline-caching/), without having to rely on promises by the optimizer. The following pseudocode describes how the **pre-compiled iterator** works for any object with the three properties `['a', 'b', 'c']` in given order:

```
doSomethingWith('a', o.a)
doSomethingWith('b', o.b)
doSomethingWith('c', o.c)
```

There is no overhead. We don't need to look anything up. The compiler already can trivially compute the exact memory address of each of the properties, using the hidden type information, and it even uses the most cache-friendly order of iteration. This is also (very very close to) the fastest code you can get with `for...in` and a perfect optimizer.

## Performance Test

[image: preliminary performance results]

[This jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-with-pre-compiled-iterator) shows that the the pre-compiled iterator approach is quite a bit faster than the standard `for ... in` loop. Note though that the speed-up largely depends on how the object is created and on the complexity of the loop. Since this test only has very simple loops, you sometimes might not observe much of a speed-up. However, in some of my own tests, I was able to see a 25x speed-up of the pre-compiled iterator; or rather a significant slow-down of the `for ... in` loop, because the optimizer was not able to get rid of the string-lookups.

With [more tests coming in](http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-with-pre-compiled-iterator), we can draw some first conclusions on different optimizer implementations:

1. The pre-compiled iterator is generally performing a whole lot better, even in very simple loops.
2. In IE, the two approaches show the least variance. Bravo Microsoft for writing a decent iteration optimizer (at least for this particular problem)!
3. In Firefox, `for ... in` is the slowest by a huge margin. The iteration optimizer does not do a good job over there.

However, the tests have a very simple loop body. I am still looking for a test case where the optimizer can never achieve constant indexing, across all (or almost all) browsers. Any suggestions are very welcome!

## Code

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5so5zypk/2/).

The following `compileIterator` function pre-compiles an iterator for any type of (simple) object (disregarding nested properties, for now). The iterator needs a bit of extra information, representing the exact type of all objects it should iterate over. Such type information can generally be represented as an array of string property names, of the exact order, which the `declareType`  function takes to create a convenient type object. If you want to see a more complete example, refer to the [jsperf entry](http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-with-pre-compiled-iterator).

```
//
// Fast object iterators in JavaScript.
//

// ########################################################################
// Type Utilities (define once, then re-use for the life-time of our application)
// ########################################################################

/**
  * Compiles and returns the "pre-compiled iterator" for any type of given properties.
  */
var compileIterator = function(typeProperties) {
  // pre-compile constant iteration over object properties
  var iteratorFunStr = '(function(obj, cb) {\n';
  for (var i = 0; i < typeProperties.length; ++i) {
    // call callback on i'th property, passing key and value
    iteratorFunStr += 'cb(\'' + typeProperties[i] + '\', obj.' + typeProperties[i] + ');\n';
  };
  iteratorFunStr += '})';

  // actually compile and return the function
  return eval(iteratorFunStr);
};

// Construct type-information and iterator for a performance-critical type, from an array of property names
var declareType = function(propertyNamesInOrder) {
  var self = {
    // "type description": listing all properties, in specific order
    propertyNamesInOrder: propertyNamesInOrder,

    // compile iterator function for this specific type
    forEach: compileIterator(propertyNamesInOrder),

    // create new object with given properties of given order, and matching initial values
    construct: function(initialValues) {
      //var o = { _type: self };     // also store type information?
      var o = {};
      propertyNamesInOrder.forEach((name) => o[name] = initialValues[name]);
      return o;
    }
  };
  return self;
};
```

And here is how we use it:

```
// ########################################################################
// Declare any amount of types (once per application run)
// ########################################################################

var MyType = declareType(['a', 'b', 'c']);


// ########################################################################
// Run-time stuff (we might do these things again and again during run-time)
// ########################################################################

// Object `o` (if not overtly tempered with) will always have the same hidden class, 
// thereby making life for the optimizer easier:
var o = MyType.construct({a: 1, b: 5, c: 123});

// Sum over all properties of `o`
var x = 0;
MyType.forEach(o, function(key, value) { 
  // console.log([key, value]);
  x += value; 
});
console.log(x);
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5so5zypk/2/).

Comment: I'm curious to see how this line of reasoning pans out in non-Chrome browsers.

Comment: @MattBall I updated my answer with a first analysis of the test results. Looks pretty good!

Comment: *Update*: I finally cleaned up the code and added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5so5zypk/2/) to make it easier to get started :)

Comment: Keep in mind that while this lowers cpu cost, it increases memory cost. The `eval`'d function could consist of a huge number of operations, if it's compiled for a huge object.

Comment: @GershomMaes Yes, there is some minor memory cost involved. However in regard to your second argument, don't forget: the `eval` part is ["offline" computational cost](https://artint.info/2e/html/ArtInt2e.Ch1.S4.SS1.html) (i.e. you do it once before the critical codepath starts, or the first time it is used), while using the compiled function is the only (much faster) "online" computational cost (the one that does affect your critical path).

Comment: No doubt about it! Once compiled this will get you faster processing speed. The memory cost isn't necessarily trivial - it's proportional to the size of the object in question.

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively use Object.getOwnPropertyNames to get the keys of the object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

```
var obj = {a:"a",b:"b"}
///{a: "a", b: "b"}
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
///(2) ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: weird how is this different than `Object.keys()`?

Comment: Keys get only enumerable properties, getOwnPropertyNames gets all the properties (except the hidden ones like __proto__)

Answer (score 3):

Object.keys() coupled with the traditonal for loop to iterate over the keys, and lookup for the values out performs all other techniques. Here is a comprehensive performance comparison.

https://gists.cwidanage.com/2018/06/how-to-iterate-over-object-entries-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to clear and detailed article. Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The `for/in` loop is the best way to enumerate properties of a Javascript object.  It should be understood that this will only loop through "enumerable" properties, and in no particular order.  Not all properties are enumerable.  All properties/methods added programmatically via your own Javascript code will be enumerable, but predefined properties/methods that are inherited (such as `toString`) are not usually enumerable.

You can check enumerability like so...

```
var o = new Object();
alert(o.propertyIsEnumerable("toString"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicit use of `Iterator` in JavaScript 1.7+ might be faster or slower. Of course this will only iterate an object's **own** properties. The catch statement also might be faster with `ex instanceof StopIteration` replaced with `ex === StopIteration`.

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6},
   iter = new Iterator(obj, true);

while (true) {
    try {
        doSomethingWithProperty(iter.next());
    } catch (ex if (ex instanceof StopIteration)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception thrown will slow things down a whole lot on the loop tail. This might be worth performance testing for very large objects/dictionaries though...

Comment: Thankfully, V8 has recently released the long awaited try-catch loop optimization. This makes it so that the code is just as fast inside a try/catch as outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the names of the properties, `for..in` is a good way to enumerate them.  If you do, you're better off with explicit dereference.

Answer (score -4):

An object's properties are unordered by definition. The lack of order means that there is no "forwards", and therefore there is no "backwards" either.

Comment: I couldn't care less about order. By "similar to decreasing while loop" I meant something analogous in terms of a speed improvement.

Comment: Actually the object property order is defined -- it's order of addition.  Order of properties on the prototype chain becomes more gnarly.

Comment: @olliej - No, the enumeration order of properties is explicitly not defined in the ECMAScript spec. It is implementation dependent and may vary between different objects. An observed order for certain objects in certain browsers should not be relied on universally

Comment: I was about to say it was defined in ES5, but it in fact stays undefined in the final April draft (section 12.6.4 The for-in Statement)

Comment: @ollie, @Tim Down: worthy of note is the further fact that there is no guarantee that an object's properties will be returned *in the same order on two consecutive iterations*, even though no properties have been either added, removed, or modified. I'm not aware of an implementation that is so obnoxious as to just return things in a different randomly-generated sequence each time, but such an implementation would in fact be in conformance with the ECMAScript spec. Any code that relies on the order of insertion being the order of enumeration is broken; to rely on unspecified behaviour is a bug.

Comment: @NickFitz: full agreement here.