# how to optimize code in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization

I think the code(below) is optimized (just use less variables than my initial version of the same logic).

1. How do I really know if its properly optimized ?
2. What factors should I consider during optimization ?

Here is the code (
[also on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbk4ts23/4/) )

```
function process(arr){
  var processed = [];
  for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
      if(processed.indexOf(arr[i]) < 0){
          var nodes = findIndexes(arr,arr[i]);
          if(nodes.length > 1){
              for(var j=0,jlen=nodes.length;j<jlen;j++){
                arr[nodes[j]] = arr[nodes[j]] + '(' + ( j + 1 ) + ')';
            }
          }
          processed.push(arr[i]);
      }
   }
   return arr;
 }

function findIndexes(arr,val){
  var node = [];
  for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
      if(arr[i] === val){
          node.push(i);
      }
  }
  return node;
}

// input
var arr = ['aa','bb','bb','aa','cc','dd','cc','ff']

console.log(process(arr));
//output: ["aa(1)", "bb(1)", "bb(2)", "aa(2)", "cc(1)", "dd", "cc(2)", "ff"]
```

Here is the explanation of the code. 'process' function looks for the same values inside array and for every same values it changes the value by post pending a number to that values, "number" indicates the count of the value as it found in array.

for example
arr = ["x","x","y","z"] will return ["x(1)","x(2)","y","z"]
 "y" and "z" are unchanged because they appeared only once.

To optimize I have used an array named as processed that is used to hold values that are just processed inside main for loop, so in next iterations it can be determined that the new iteration value is already processed or not by checking through the array.indexOf method, if the value is already processed then it can safely skip the underlying logic (if/for statements).

Now I have no idea how to further optimize it other than changing the whole process logic.

Comment: Your code may be optimized for performance alright, but for readability, that is another matter...

Comment: This seems as if it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com if there's not a *question* here.

Comment: You can use a web worker for performing this looping stuff(in a separate thread) if this is making your pages irresponsive(if you are using html5)

Comment: @SebasSBM OP should definitely not do that, it's bad practice. How does that make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single loop:

```
function process2(arr) {
    var out = arr.slice(0),
        seen = {},
        len = arr.length,
        i, key, item, count;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        key = out[i];
        item = seen[key];
        if (!item) {
            // firstIndex, count
            seen[key] = item = [i, 0];
        }
        count = ++item[1];
        if (count > 1) {
            if (count === 2) {
                out[item[0]] = key + '(1)';
            }
            out[i] = key + '(' + count + ')';
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// input
var arr = ['aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'cc', 'ff']

console.time('p2');
console.log(process2(arr));
console.timeEnd('p2');
```

From benchmarking, `process2` is approximately 2x faster than `process1`. That's just a really naive first pass at the problem.

Comment: i think your answer definitely increases the performance and i am gonna mark it as answer too but it doesn't answer my 2nd main concern that is "What factors should I consider during optimization ?". However, its answered by @utility

Comment: What @utility posted doesn't really help you much, a vast majority of it is about DOM operations. The stuff about the performance analysis doesn't really provide much either. Typically, you will trade memory for speed. My solution needs to use more memory to keep a cache of things we've seen already, but means it's faster because it only loops once. Your solution uses less memory, but it slower because it needs to keep looking through the array. The main thing for these kinds of problems is algorithmic complexity and choosing the right data structures and tradeoffs (memory/speed).

Answer (score 4):

Optimizations in a broad sense will involve simplifying code, precomputing results which are repeatedly reused, and organizing code so more results can be reused.

Your fiddle code produced following result on analysis.

```
Logical LOC: 26
Mean parameter count: 3
Cyclomatic complexity: 7
Cyclomatic complexity density: 27%
Maintainability index: 104
```

**Lines of Code** (LOC)– Indicates the approximate number of lines in the code. The count is based on the IL code and is therefore not the exact number of lines in the source code file. A very high count might indicate that a type or method is trying to do too much work and should be split up. It might also indicate that the type or method might be hard to maintain.

**Maintainability Index** – Calculates an index value between 0 and 100 that represents the relative ease of maintaining the code. A high value means better maintainability. Color coded ratings can be used to quickly identify trouble spots in your code. A green rating is between 20 and 100 and indicates that the code has good maintainability. A yellow rating is between 10 and 19 and indicates that the code is moderately maintainable. A red rating is a rating between 0 and 9 and indicates low maintainability.

**Cyclomatic Complexity** – Measures the structural complexity of the code. It is created by calculating the number of different code paths in the flow of the program. A program that has complex control flow will require more tests to achieve good code coverage and will be less maintainable.

Check  code complexities using [online tool](http://jscomplexity.org/#results) for your javascript code.

Reference : [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192045/how-to-optimize-javascript-jquery-code-to-speed-up-its-performance),[Link 2](http://desalasworks.com/article/javascript-performance-techniques/)

[Javascript optimiser page](http://js-optimizer.sourceforge.net/2.2.3/)

[Reference](http://desalasworks.com/article/javascript-performance-techniques/)(Provides you with different techniques that you should keep in mind while optimising)

Comment: it will be great if you can explain these parameters.

Comment: thanks for the reference link. very helpful. answered my 2nd question.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way to optimize your code with less changes:

In your specific case you go through the whole array for each new found entry although all previous entries have already been processed so it should be possible to opimize further by passing the current index to findIndexes:

```
function findIndexes(arr,val, fromIndex){
  var node = [];
  for(var i=fromIndex,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
      if(arr[i] === val){
          node.push(i);
      }
  }
  return node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currrently your code has a `O(n^2)` complextity. This is caused by your outer loop of `arr` in `process` then a call to `findIndexes` which again loops through `arr`.

You can simplify this to an `O(n)` algorithm that loops through the array twice:

```
function process(arr) {
    var result = [];
    var counter = {}, counts = {};

    var len = arr.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){   
        var value = arr[i];

        counter[value] = 1;
        counts[value] = (counts[value] || 0) + 1;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){   
        var value = arr[i];

        if(counts[value] == 1) {
            result.push(value);   
        } else {
            result.push(value + "(" + counter[value]++ + ")");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that doesn't use nested loops, and uses an object to store key information:

```
var obj = {};

// loop over the array storing the elements as keys in the object
// if a duplicate element is found, increment the count value
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var key = arr[i];
  if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = { count: 0, level: 0 };
  obj[key].count++;
}

// remove all the key/values where the count is 1
// ie there are no duplicates
for (var p in obj) {
  if (obj[p].count ===  1) delete obj[p];
}

// for each element in the original array, increase its 'level'
// amend the element with the count
// reduce the count
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var key = arr[i];
    if (obj[key] && obj[key].count > 0) {
      obj[key].level++;
      arr[i] = key + '(' + obj[key].level + ')';
      obj[key].count--;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/31j704p9/2/)

Comment: That doesn't produce the correct output: `["aa(1)", "bb(1)", "bb(1)", "aa(1)", "cc(1)", "dd", "cc(1)", "ff"]`

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, @EvanTrimboli. Correct result is now:`[ "aa(1)", "bb(1)", "bb(2)", "aa(2)", "cc(1)", "dd", "cc(2)", "ff" ]`