# If you want force garbage collection on a variable in Javascript, is it better to set it as null or undefined?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am developing an Android game using JS framework. I want to make sure that some of the objects are garbage collected once I am done using them. How do i force it? Should I use null or undefined?

Comment: It's hard to write JS these days that doesn't GC properly. Don't worry about it. If you're done with objects, they will be garbage collected. If they aren't it's a bug in the JS runtime. In the worst case, this is something you deal with at the optimzation phase, but it doesn't affect the architecture.

Answer (score 9):

You can't force garbage collection (not in any sane fashion).

If your variables aren't going out of scope automatically, just set them to `null`.

Answer (score 9):

Best advice is to define them in scope that makes them eligible for garbage collection. This means don't use global variables that never become eligible for collection. Instead declare them as locals.

Comment: Are you saying that globals are never candidates for garbage collection?  For example, if I set a `window.bigdata = create5meg()`, and then later set the global to `window.bigdata = null;`, that the 5 meg of data will not be garbage collected?

Answer (score 5):

You could set it to null, and if that is then the last reference to that object, it will become eligible for garbage collection.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/

TGH's suggestion is the best though, I'd recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want force garbage collection on a variable in Javascript, is it better to set it as null or undefined?

Doesn't matter, you can even set it to another object *you* created: as long as the object originally referenced by the variable is no longer referenced anywhere, it can be garbage collected. Think of your object as "something being referenced by variables".

If no variables reference it, it can be garbage collected, and "putting another object into a variable" will make the variable no longer reference the previous object.

---

> I want to make sure that some of the objects are garbage collected once I am done using them. How do i **force** it?

You can force *major* garbage collection to be triggered in a Node-based runtime (e.g. Electron or NW.js), by using the `--expose-gc` flag and running:

```
global.gc();
```

If your app/game is browser-based, in Chrome only you can use the `--allow-natives-syntax` switch (your users would need to pass this to Chrome themselves), and call:

```
%CollectGarbage();
```

*Note: dead simple, but you might as well just do a `window.location.reload()` as a fallback, if you can easily continue from where you left off (e.g. reload the game into another level, if you will).*

Remember, however, these calls won't screw around, and can block for whole *seconds* if there is a lot of garbage to collect. This can be ideal if you have determined pauses in your game, such as loading screens between levels, but tricky otherwise.

You might also want to consider using an [object pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410667/object-pools-in-high-performance-javascript), with or without using manual garbage collection, to simply reduce garbage and improve performance.