# Remove event handler function from window?

Tags: javascript

If I've added a function to the window object like this:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And lets say my code may run this snippet many times is there a danger in a memory leak? (since I never "delete" that function from the window [SPA])

And just to be on the safe side I prefer to remove that function when my component dies (angularjs2 by the way) how can I "unbind" a function from the window object?

I hope I understand right that each time I call `window.onclick = function(...)` I **add** a function and not replacing one

Comment: You cannot remove a specific *anonymous* event handler.

Comment: `window.onclick = null;`? Or use addEventListener and removeEventListener instead.

Comment: @ManoDestra I come from C background if I do the `=null` will the garbage collector remove my function from the browser memory? also does it remove **all** the functions on the window object? there may be some there that were defined by different scripts and I don't want to mess them around

Comment: @BenM is there a way to remove a named function?

Comment: You can remove a named function using removeEventListener. Don't know about garbage collection regarding the function. You'd need to know what each browser does with this.

Comment: @kfir124 Please see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478655/if-you-want-force-garbage-collection-on-a-variable-in-javascript-is-it-better-t

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot remove a specific *anonymous* event handler from an object when using the `onEVENT` syntax. Whenever you call `object.onclick =`, you overwrite whatever is currently assigned to the `onclick` property of `object`.

You will need to use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) with a named function:

```
function windowClicker(event) 
{
    if (event.target == modal) 
    {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

// Add the listener:
window.addEventListener('click', windowClicker, false);

// Remove it:
window.removeEventListener('click', windowClicker, false);
```

Comment: When you say that all event handlers will be removed, what do you mean? onclick only has one event handler on it when set via window.onclick = function() {}, so when you set that to null, it removes that function. Any handlers added via addEventListener, still exist. Not sure if it's browser specific, but I just tested this behavior on Firefox.

Comment: @ManoDestra What I mean is, if you consider this code (https://jsfiddle.net/zsvdnhfb/), assigning to `null` does not allow us to remove **only** the second anonymous function, for example.

Comment: The 2nd function overwrites the 1st function. The null then removes the 2nd function only. Not sure if that's what you mean? You can't have multiple functions set via onclick. You need addEventListener for that, to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, perhaps my choice of words is confusing, though. I will update the answer to better reflect what I am saying.

Answer (score 7):

For a named function, use addEventListener and removeEventListener...

```
window.addEventListener('click', windowClickHandler, false);
window.removeEventListener('click', windowClickhandler, false);
```

You can have as many event listeners on an element, using the above method.

For unnamed functions, use...

```
window.onclick = function(event) { // do stuff; };
window.onclick = null;
```

You can only have **ONE** event handler set using the above method. Each window.onclick set using this method overwrites the previous one. Setting it to null simply removes the last one set.

It's up to each browser how it implements its garbage collection with regards to these calls.

Comment: Thanks. JS is really confusing if you don't know the very accurate use cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you add event like

```
window.onclick = function() {
    // some stuff..
}
```

Then there is only *one* `onclick` listener and you can remove it just like

```
window.onclick = undefined;
```

But if you want to remove named function then you can do something like this:

```
function abc(event) {
    // do something
}

window.addEventListener('click', abc); // add the listener

window.removeEventListener('click', abc); // remove the listener
```

And you can add multiple 'onclick' listeners like this, but you have to keep the reference to them, so anonymous functions are kept forever (till the page is reloaded).

Comment: Well, the `window.onclick = ...` will always listen just with one function, so if you do `window.onclick = ...` again it will simply get overridden. So the *all* handlers you mention are exactly the last one you attached.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign to `element.onEVENT`, you can remove the binding by assigning `null` or `undefined` to the same property. Assigning to properties does not add, it replaces.

If you want to add multiple event handlers, you need to use [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You can then remove handlers with [`element.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). But to use this, you'll have to use a named function, since the remove call needs to provide the same function that was previously added, and you can't do that if you don't assign the function to a name.