# Loading many Audio files in Javascript Windows Store App

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm having difficulty playing Audio in a Windows store app.  I'm using JavaScript.  The code is below.

When I try to play a sound from the array of over 200 sounds (average size 15KB), it sounds like a Cylon, from Battlestar Galactica, is attacking my app.  If I wait long enough it's OK, or if the array of sounds is less then it obviously loads faster too.

Is there an event or some way to determine when the app is ready to play all sounds?  Or a better approach?

```
var play = new Array("over", "200", "sounds", "in", "this", "list", "that", "average", "15KB");

for (var i = 0; i< play.length; ++i){
           tmpAudio = new Audio("/sound/" + words[i] + ".mp3");
           play[i] = tmpAudio;
}

something.onClick = function () {
           play[soundPos].play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the thing is I believe in the for loop, what you are mainly doing is loading all of the sound files into memory (too much caching) first which as expected will slow things down.

I would suggest a few changes:

1- Use [] for array creation

2- Cache a var arrayLength = play.length and use it in the loop instead of i < play.length as this will be checked for every element.

3- In fact I suggest you remove the loop and do a just when needed (onclick) loading of the audio file (put some loading image or canvas in there for user friendliness).

For this you might need to re-write some of your code let's say

```
var play = { sound1: urlWord, sound2: urlWord, sound3: urlWord,......};
```

Although not array (arrays are weirdly implemented in JS interpreters)
you might loop on it as in the following link:
[stackoverflow link on iterating over objects mainly for in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573593/whats-the-fastest-way-to-iterate-over-an-objects-properties-in-javascript)

in the onclick:

```
  something.onClick = function () {
//if the below works or else just use a temp var
    new Audio("/sound/" + play[soundPos] + ".mp3").play();        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm kicking myself, and thanking you too!  Yes, all I really need to do is onClick new Audio and play.  Thanks again.