# how to create a hash map so I can loop through or delete in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried creating a hashMap in JavaScript

```
var map ={};
 // the key is string values that I don't know when I want to access
 // values are objects
```

I want to be able to loop through the map. 
I want to be able to delete a map pair by using a key.

I tried a bunch of different things I saw online and none of those worked.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, there is [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is ES2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to iterate over an object's properties in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573593/whats-the-fastest-way-to-iterate-over-an-objects-properties-in-javascript)

Comment: Just use professional quality data structure library. Bucket-JS is my suggestion.

    https://github.com/mauriciosantos/Buckets-JS/blob/master/src/dictionary.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var map = {};
    map[0] = 1;
    map[1] = 1;
    //Key/value pair
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(map).length; i++) {
        var itemValue = map[i];
    }
    delete map[0];
```

String based key/value

```
    var map = {};
    map["00"] = "0";
    map["11"] = "1";
    map["22"] = "2";

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(map).length; i++) {
        var itemValue = map[Object.keys(map)[i]];
        //delete map[Object.keys(map)[i]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for-in` statement is supposed to do just that. If I populate the object, I can loop through same-level properties as such:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for(key in obj){
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

// Output:
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Now, to delete a key-value pair, you'd have to use the `delete` operator. Transforming the previous example:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for(key in obj){
    delete obj[key];
}

console.log(obj);

// Output:
// {}
```

The syntax above is standard JavaScript, supported since ES1.